# THREE.js rotation copy is not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

I have a bug where I copy the `Quaternion` of one object and pass it to a function where it gets applied to another object to keep their rotations in sync. I cannot get the `Quaternion` to apply to the second object.

Given object 1 is `msh` and object 2 is `msh2`, this code will not apply the rotation of `msh` to `msh2`

```
  var rot = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(msh.rotation);
  msh2.rotation.copy(rot);
```

You can see this further in this Stack Snippet which contains the problem in the smallest reproducable fashion (but isn't the exact code I'm working with in my real project)

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas : $("#can")[0]});
renderer.setSize($("#can").width(), $("#can").height());
var cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, $("#can").width() / $("#can").height(), 0.1, 100);
cam.position.set(0,2,6);
cam.quaternion.multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), -Math.PI/8 ));
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0xff0000});
var msh = new THREE.Mesh(geo,mat);
scene.add(msh);

geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,2,1);
mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0xff00ff});
var msh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geo,mat);
msh2.position.set(2,0,0);
scene.add(msh2);

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  msh.rotateX(0.001);
  msh.rotateY(0.002);
  //For some reason, this doesn't work??
  var rot = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(msh.rotation);
  msh2.rotation.copy(rot);
  //Yet this does (but it doesn't fit the flow of my
  //original project because I don't want to pass
  //objects around.
  //msh2.rotation.copy(msh.rotation);
  renderer.render( scene, cam );
}
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

[Also see the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1avv71q0/10/)

Am I missing something here? I do this with `Vector3` all the time so I don't see why I can't do it here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

msh.rotation is an instance of THREE.Euler, but you're trying to copy to/from THREE.Quaternion. msh2.rotation.copy(msh.rotation) should work fine, as would msh2.quaternion.copy(msh.quaternion)

Comment: Agh, I knew it was something dumb. I was doing console traces and it *looked* like it was updating properly. Explains why my `_w` property was always undefined, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want both objects to rotate at the same speed and angle. You just need to update the `render();` function with these two lines:

```
  msh2.rotateX(0.001);
  msh2.rotateY(0.002);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1avv71q0/11/)

Comment: That's just the snippet of the problem reproduced in the smallest way. In my actual project `I copy the Quaternion of one object and pass it to a function where it gets applied to another object to keep their rotations in sync` as I said in the first paragraph. The rotation is coming from mouse controls controlling a camera with really nontrivial rotations so I can't reproduce them like that.